# Can't change kivy screen inside a gridlayout

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to have a grid layout with two columns. The left column has a stacklayout with buttons and the idea is when pressed, the info shows in the right column. However I cant get it to work. Any ideas? (You can see in the code that I only tried with "agujeros". I'm fairly new to programming so any help will come in handy!

Python file:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 

kivy.require('1.11.1')

class PantallaPrincipal(BoxLayout):
    pass

class AgujerosNegros(Screen):
    pass

class MateriaOscura(Screen):
    pass

class EnergiaOscura(Screen):
    pass

class Exoplanetas(Screen):
    pass

class SistemaSolar(Screen):
    pass

class Telescopios(Screen):
    pass

class LaLuna(Screen):
    pass

class DatoAlAzar(Screen):
    pass

class Bibliografia(Screen):
    pass

class PantallaInfo(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class AstronoMeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return PantallaPrincipal()
         
if __name__ == '__main__':
    AstronoMeApp().run()
```

.KV File:

```
WindowManager:
    AgujerosNegros:
        id: "agujeros"
    MateriaOscura:
    EnergiaOscura:
    Exoplanetas:
    SistemaSolar:
    Telescopios:
    LaLuna:
    DatoAlAzar:
    Bibliografia:
    PantallaInfo:
    
<AgujerosNegros>:
    Label:
        text: "Hola"

<PantallaPrincipal>:
    BoxLayout:
        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            cols_minimum: {0: .3, 1: 630}
            
            StackLayout:

                orientation: 'tb-lr'
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgb: .3, .6, .6
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size

                Button:
                    text: "Inicio" 
                    size_hint: [1 ,.1]
                    text_size: self.size
                    halign: 'center'
                    valign: 'center'


                Button:
                    text: "Agujeros negros" 
                    size_hint: [1 ,.1]
                    text_size: self.size
                    halign: 'center'
                    valign: 'center'
                    on_release: 
                        app.root.current = "agujeros"

                    
                Button:
                    text: "Materia oscura"
                    size_hint: [1 ,.1]
                    text_size: self.size
                    halign: 'center'
                    valign: 'center'
                Button:
                    text: "Energ" + u"\u00ed" + "a oscura" 
                    size_hint: [1 ,.1]
                    text_size: self.size
                    halign: 'center'
                    valign: 'center'
                Button:
                    
                    text: "Exoplanetas"
                    size_hint: [1 ,.1]
                    text_size: self.size
                    halign: 'center'
                    valign: 'center'

                Button:
                    text: "Sistema solar" 
                    size_hint: [1 ,.1]
                    text_size: self.size
                    halign: 'center'
                    valign: 'center'

                Button:
                    text: "Telescopios" 
                    size_hint: [1 ,.1]
                    text_size: self.size
                    halign: 'center'
                    valign: 'center'

                Button:
                    text: "La luna" 
                    size_hint: [1 ,.1]
                    text_size: self.size
                    halign: 'center'
                    valign: 'center'

                Button:
                    text: "Dato al azar"
                    size_hint: [1 ,.1]
                    text_size: self.size
                    halign: 'center'
                    valign: 'center'
                Button:
                    
                    text: "Bibliograf" + u"\u00ed" + "a"
                    size_hint: [1 ,.1]
                    text_size: self.size
                    halign: 'center'
                    valign: 'center'
                
            PantallaInfo:
                BoxLayout:
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgb: .3, .6, .6
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                    Label:
                        text: "prueba"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change `Screen` by using `app.root.current` in:

```
            Button:
                text: "Agujeros negros" 
                size_hint: [1 ,.1]
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'center'
                on_release: 
                    app.root.current = "agujeros"
```

But the `root` of your `App` is a `PantallaPrincipal` as set in:

```
class AstronoMeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return PantallaPrincipal()
```

You can only change `Screen` (using `current`) in a `ScreenManager`. So, as a first step, you need to have a `ScreenManager` as the `app.root`. You can do that by changing your `App` definition to:

```
class AstronoMeApp(App):
    pass
```

Then, your `kv` file will be automatically loaded (assuming it is named `astronome.kv`) and your `app.root` will be `WindowManager`. Then, after fixing some other errors, you can use `app.root.current` to change `Screens`.